# I am playing Minecraft 1.8.7 and I can't become an operator, even though I own the server. How do I become and operator in Minecraft 1.8.7?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

The problem is that I can't find the server console, and give the command `op playername`. I just can't figure it out and having trouble with server consoles, and that ops.txt. I can't find it.

Comment: We need more information. Why don't you have access to the console? Where is the server running? Same for why you can not access the files.. If you are running the server where did you put the files and launch it from?We need more information as to what you Are seeing to help guide you.

Comment: I cant find the server consle. do you mean by the computer or something?  I know where it all is, but i just dont and cant find the ops.txt thing for adding operators in. :(

Comment: I know where ALL of the server files are and am looking in them- but i cant find ops.txt in them and cant figure out what to do.

Comment: Run the server once and it should generate the files, it does not come with them by default but makes empty ones.. But if you can run the server it should pop up the console and you can just type the command like normal into that console.

Answer (score 2):

Write the following into the Server Console to OP a Player:

> op [playername]

You csn remove OP-Rights by using the following command:

> deop [playername]

Every OP can op and deop other players

Alternatively you can edit the document in your server folder that contains the op names. Its enough to write your playername on the first line if the document was previously empty.

Minecraft will convert that name into the new OP-saving-method which also saves permission level if the document is completely empty besides the list of names. (Every playername on seperate lines)

Comment: From the question the person knows of the commands and the file, but can not find the console window to type it into nor the file to enter the values into.